# Send/receive faxes through Google Voice without using a fax machine?

Tags: google-voice

Once in a while I bump into an antiquated bureaucratic process that requires sending or receiving a fax. Back in the dialup days I was glad that I no longer needed a fax machine to send and receive faxes. However, I no longer have a land line so I end up having to pay an office supply store or a print shop for faxing services. [Google Voice](http://voice.google.com) has been very useful for voice calls, however I was disappointed to find that it has no *official* support for [sending](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=0c07c84a0dfada53&hl=en) or [receiving](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=4cd73ec0889411b2&hl=en) faxes.

Here is some information that may help find a solution:

- The ability to print to fax using a dialup modem has been available for a long time.
- Someone already figured out how to send faxes by forwarding the call to a [fax machine connected to a land line](http://ascend4.org/Faxing_via_Google_Voice).
- Someone already figured out how to get a [stable 40 Kbps dialup connection over Google Voice](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=799df7efa0820730&hl=en) and thought about fax support.
- Some people believe that [modem](https://serverfault.com/questions/99903/how-can-i-simulate-a-modem-over-a-voip-connection) and [fax](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/voice/thread?tid=29320de86776827b&hl=en) communication over VoIP are too fragile to be functional.

I know there are many sites that provide faxing services for a fee, however I want to consider solutions using Google Voice. I was starting to think of a virtual dialup modem that somehow used Google Voice, but would rather read your suggestions of an existing solution or a simpler approach.

Answer (score 4):

I use my ObiHai paired to my Google Voice account.

I have my fax machine on line #2 and my home phones on line #1, on the ObiHai. The ObiHai detects when a fax comes in and sends it to line #2 and voice is line #1. Simple and effective.

Answer (score 2):

One method might be to use an [Obihai 110](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0045RMEPI), connect it to a modem on your computer, and use a computer faxing program or a built-in [fax service (Windows)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/Set-up-your-computer-to-send-and-receive-faxes). This [CNET article has some interesting info](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10330490-263.html). This [PBX in a Flash forum post](http://pbxinaflash.com/forum/showthread.php?t=10116) is also interesting.

Answer (score -1):

> I thought I was stuck until I discovered a feature of GV called 'temporary call forwarding' and paired that with some inspiration from
>   Rupert Murdoch and the infamous voicemail hacking scandal by Called-ID
>   spoofing my own fax number!
>
> About 'temporary call forwarding' GV allows you to setup  'temporary
>   call forwarding' for instances when you are on vacation, staying at a
>   friends house, etc. To set this up, you do not need to verify the
>   telephone number. You only need to call your GV number and access the
>   settings menu using your PIN.
>
> http://support.google.com/voice/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=115084
>
> About Caller-ID spoofing In short, it allows you to display any number
>   on a caller-ID regardless of where the call is actually coming from.
>
> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID_spoofing
>
> How to Do it:
>
> 1. Get a GV # if you don't already have one:
>      https://www.google.com/voice
> 2. Configure a PIN so you can access the GV settings via phone under
>      the Voicemail & Text tab:

see the following helpful blog for more info

http://nbiq.blogspot.com/2012/03/using-google-voice-with-your-online-fax.html